# Adding excel formula as part of a range

Tags: excel, formula

I am looking to add a formula as part of a range reference. Below is an example:

=sumif(F2:indirect("F" & B5),....and so on....)

Essentially I have a lot of formulas referencing a range of data that is always changing in terms of the number of rows. The goal is as the row number changes, users can just enter in the new row number and all the formulas will update automatically. Cell B5 houses the row number and is the input cell that users would update.

I have tried many different methods, everything from INDIRECT, CELL, to other methods and cannot get it to work. I have formatted B5 as text, number, and general but it still does not work.

Any ideas on how to make this work? I have seen similar questions asked on other forums and tried their methods and still get nothing but #VALUE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INDEX` is better than `INDIRECT` - you can use this as a range in `SUMIF`

`F2:INDEX(F:F,B5)`

where B5 contains a number

although `SUMIF/COUNTIF` etc. usually calculate using only the "used range" so it's often as efficient just to use the whole column like F:F, even if you only have 500 rows of data